# Hashset ordering issue

Tags: java, hashset, treeset

Recently I came across this

```
String s = "9495963";
Set<Character> set = new HashSet<Character>();
for(char e : s.toCharArray()){
  set.add(e);
}
System.out.println(set);//[3, 4, 5, 6, 9]
```

The output i got was [3, 4, 5, 6, 9], so, if HashSet doesn't preserve any order then how come these numbers were arranged in the ascending order?

Comment: There is no _guarantee_ of order when iterating the hash set.  That doesn't mean there is anything _wrong_ with you seeing those values in order.

Comment: I understand both LinkedHashSet preserves insertion order and TreeSet rearrange to ascending order, but if HashSet is not ordered, then why that output?

Comment: Use LinkedHashSet. this maintains the insertion order, TreeSet is used to get the sorted order of inserted elements.

Comment: @kjunz there are 5! (120) ways of arranging 5 things. The elements could appear in any one of those 120 ways; any one of them is equally valid.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Coincidence. It just happens that the hashCode of Character is it’s numeric value. If you keep adding more characters than there are hash buckets in the HashSet, you’ll see that they get out of order.

Answer (score 2):

`HashSet` uses a `HashMap` internally.

`HashMap` stores its elements in a hash table using each Object's `hashCode()` method.

For Character class, the hashcode is it's corresponding int value.

```
public static int hashCode(char value) {
    return (int)value;
}
```

For `int` and `double` datatypes, these are [auto-boxed](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) into the `Integer` and `Double` classes. When you make a `HashSet` of `int`s, it uses [Integer's hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#hashCode()) method, which just returns the `int`. So if you add `int`s, they get stored in a sorted order.

But for `double`, [Double's hashCode()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#hashCode()) method is much more complicated, because of the way doubles are represented in memory.

But, over time, when the elements exceed the bucket size, you'll see it won't maintain order.